# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ coincides with the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S$ be a set and let $\mathcal{F} = \{\{s\}:s\in S\}$ be the collection consisting of all sets which contain one element of $S$.

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A\subseteq S:A \text{ is countable or $A^c$ is countable}\}$ be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra for $S$.

**Question** How do I show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$, coincides with the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$?

I assume coincides means 'is' here, please correct me if I'm wrong. The idea of $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ was just introduced to me and I'm not so sure how to use it. I know that $\mathcal{A}$ is in fact an $\sigma$-algebra and I understand that $\mathcal{F}$ is contained by $\mathcal{A}$, but I don't know how to show that there is no smaller $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{F}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can explicitly build a countable set out of singletons and cocountable sets out of countable sets using constructions every $\sigma$-algebra is closed under.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$.
We need to see that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$, and we have minimality and so  $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{A}$.

So let $A$ be countable, then enumerate $A$ as $A = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
Then for all $n$, $\{a_n\} \in \mathcal{F}$ so $\{a_n\} \in \mathcal{S}$ as well.
And as the latter is a $\sigma$-algebra, $A = \cup_n \{a_n\} \in \mathcal{S}$.

Now, if $A$ is cocountable, then $X\setminus A$ is countable so $X \setminus A \in \mathcal{S}$ by the above paragraph. But $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under complements so $X \setminus (X\setminus A) = A \in \mathcal{S}$ as well.

So all members of $\mathcal{A}$ are in $\mathcal{S}$ as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand why every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$ now. However, how do you know that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq\mathcal{S}$? I don't know what minimality means, I've looked it up but that didn't make it more clear.

Comment: @titusAdam Let $A\in\mathcal A$. Evidently $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ so if $A$ is countable then it appears to be a countable union of elements of $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal S$. Then it is legitimate to conclude that $A\in\mathcal S$ because as a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal S$ is closed under countable unions. If $A$ is co-countable then with the same reasoning we find $A^{\complement}\in\mathcal S$. Also $\mathcal S$ is closed under complements so we conclude that $A=(A^{\complement})^{\complement}\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: @titusAdam every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$ is the *definition* of $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$!! So if you see one you see the other.

Comment: @titusAdam minimality is using that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ is by definition the **smallest** sigma-algebra that contains $\mathcal{F}$. So if we show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of *any* $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{F}$ it is the minimal one and thus equals $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$. The minimality is equivalent to defining $$\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \bigcap\{ \mathcal{S} : \mathcal{S} \text{ a sigma-algebra and } \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{S} \}$$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I can't believe I asked that, sorry!